ActivityCompat.requestPermissions didn't show permission dialog again after denying 2 times
I'm tried to handle multiple Android permissions using Java. I'm using checkPermissions function like this :
public void checkPermissions() { //Suppose I trying Android 14 version, SDK 34
    ...
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 32){
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO,
                    Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT,
                    Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN
            }, 1);
        } else {
            isPermissionGranted = true;
            return;
        }
    }
    ...
}

and then continues to onRequestPermissionsResult
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1:
            ...
            else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 32){

                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                        && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                        && grantResults[2] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                        && grantResults[3] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                        && grantResults[4] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    isPermissionGranted = true;
                    Log.e("permission","isPermissionGranted, onRequestPermissionsResult SDK INT " + Build.VERSION.SDK_INT + " : " +isPermissionGranted);
                    setBluetoothConnection(mBluetoothAdapter);
                }
                else {
                    isPermissionGranted = false;
                    showNeedPermissionsDialog();
                    Log.e("permission","isPermissionGranted, onRequestPermissionsResult SDK INT " + Build.VERSION.SDK_INT + " : " +isPermissionGranted);
                }
            }
            break;
        ...
    }
}

If user denied, continues to showPermissionDialog function and click btnClose to close the app.
private void showPermissionDialog() {
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_permission_needed);
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
    dialog.setCancelable(false);

    Button btnClose = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnClose);

    btnClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            finish();
        }
    });
    dialog.show();
}

The problem is, after I close the app and open it again when I denied permission 2 times, the Android permission dialog is not showing (not showPermissionDialog function). So, why it not showing after denied 2 times? And how do I solve it?
Note : If it possible, please do not use intent settings to approve permissions

After user denies a permission twice its implied they never want to see the dialog again. Older android versions did show a "don't ask again" checkbox that could be un-checked to keep showing the dialog but it was removed.

This is answer for you

How to detect permission pernantly in Android

And Following for request runtime permissions in Docs
Request Runtime Permissions
